# Rubocop ignoring excludes specified in .rubocop.yml

Tags: ruby, git, rubocop

I'm using Rubocop in CircleCI. And it's been configured to ignore the db folder. But it is still coming back with exceptions. I'm using a custom rake task in CI that is likely the cause. How can I modify it so that it ignores those excluded files/dirs?

#### rubocop.rake

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
namespace :rubocop do
  require 'rubocop/rake_task'

  desc 'Run RuboCop on entire project'
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new('all') do |task|
    task.fail_on_error = true
  end

  desc 'Run RuboCop on the project based on git diff(DIFF_BRANCH environment variable)'
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new('git_diff') do |task|
    task.patterns = patterns_for_changed_files
    task.fail_on_error = true
  end

  def changed_files
    diff_branch = ENV['DIFF_BRANCH'] || 'staging'
    cmd = %(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --diff-filter=M --name-only HEAD origin/#{diff_branch})
    diff = `#{cmd}`
    diff.split "\n"
    # diff.gsub!(/^(db\/|vendor\/|tmp\/|lib\/|test\/|bin\/)/, '').split "\n"
  end

  def patterns_for_changed_files
    patterns = []
    patterns + changed_files
  end
end
```

#### .rubocop.yml

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'vendor/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'
    - 'lib/**/*'
    - 'test/**/*'
    - 'bin/*'
    - 'config/**/*.yml'
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'db/schema.rb'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Rubocop from a Rake task, this is expected behaviour. Also see this [related issue on Github](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/4122).

Personally I'd recommend running it from a shell script with command line arguments instead.
To achieve the check for changed files, you can use [pronto](https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto) in conjunction with [pronto-rubocop](https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto-rubocop).

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I want the build to fail if exceptions are found. Not to leave comments.

Comment: It will also fail the build - the comments are optional sugar on top.